# How to set VPN connection to local network only?

Tags: networking, vpn

I am connecting to my workplace's network through a vpn. All I need is the local network there (offline servers, local computers and data stores). After I connected to the VPN, all of my packets go through the vpn and slows down everything for me and generates an unnecessary load on my office's internet connection (once windows started to update on my computer and it started to use most of the office's internet connection, because they only have 30/10 MBit/s internet connection).

Is it possible to set the vpn in a way, where it only allows access to the local resources?

[image]

Edit 1:

Can't I just set the default gateway off to the vpn?

[image]

Comment: It's the purpose of the VPN to integrate a remote machine into a LAN. From that, it should be obvious that you want to think in different directions. It all starts with QoS settings in the company's router and regarding updates, IT will have to find the right compromise between leaving your computer as a security risk or providing the required bandwidth. You can't expect professional behaviour from an amateur setup.

Comment: Things happen slow there, can I do anything while they fix this issue? Right now I need to connect and disconnect every time I need something, it is quite tiring. Shame I can't tell my programs which network to use.

Comment: Turns out I probably misunderstood your question. Either way, there may be ways to bypass the VPN, e.g. for Windows updates, [see here](https://www.hideipvpn.com/setup/how-to-vpn-bypass-websites-windows/).

Comment: A useful term to know is split tunneling. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling

Comment: Split tunneling needs to be approved and allowed by the IT dept. It's usually disabled for security reasons. If you do this you create an unfiltered bridge where an attack from the internet can pass through your computer, and pivot on to the corporate network. Please contact your systems administrator with this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 SplitTunneling - Internet Not Working](https://superuser.com/questions/1418316/windows-10-splittunneling-internet-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago and finally got it solved by modifying the priority windows assigns to each interface. You can do this by:

1. on a command window, run "route PRINT" and annotate the priority of the vpn and non-vpn routes.
2. go to the properties of the non-vpn interface, to the properties of tcp/ipv4 or tpc/ipv6 and click on "advanced". There you can uncheck the "automatic metric" and set another higher for that interface. 
   By doing this when a connection can be established either by the vpn or the non-vpn, the one with the higher priority will be used.

However, there is a drawback: some VPNs automatically set the priority to the highest when they boot. So, before starting the VPN you should set again the metric to automatic, start the VPN, and reset the metric to whatever number you want.

Comment: I added a picture to the question. What If I set the default gateway to off on the VPN's advanced tcp/ip settings.

Comment: probably should do the trick. If it does, tell us! :) However, I can not modify the VPN settings, only the actual interface's ones.

Comment: I tried to turn it off, but I cannot reach the remote network that way. I should look into the stuff the others linked (vpn bypass and split tunneling)