# Windows 10: How to configure firewall to use VPN only for some domains?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, network-adapter, windows-firewall, juniper

On my company laptop, I can activate the VPN connexion, but it's slow, and it will redirect all my traffic, including the web browser.

I'd like to be able to use the VPN only to SSH into the company's server. And I'd like my other traffic (internet browsing) not to use the VPN.

I think this can be achieved using the Windows Firewall, but I have no idea how.

The VPN client is Pulse Secure, and **it's managed by the company**. I can't edit its configuration, enable or disable split tunneling, or anything. I can only configure the firewall or some other rule to try and bypass it. I can't use a virtual machine to connect to the VPN and SSH from the VM. But maybe this leads to an idea for a solution: I noticed that two network adapters show up, one for my Wifi connexion and one for the VPN adapter. Is there a way to say "never use the VPN adapter, unless for this specific VM"?

This question was marked as a duplicate of [How to use one connection to the Internet for VPN and another for accessing other websites?](https://superuser.com/questions/166555/how-to-use-one-connection-to-the-internet-for-vpn-and-another-for-accessing-othe), but this other question does not explain how I can modify the proper settings in Windows directly, and I don't even know what these settings are.

Comment: Look and see if your VPN application provides an option for split tunneling. That is fairly common in commercial VPN applications. I do not think split tunneling can be emulated by Firewall settings.

Comment: Otherwise, add some static routes and only have the subnet with the SSH use the VPN interface and have a default or the rest use the internal ISP router or your usual gateway (Static Routes e.g. `ROUTE /?`, `ROUTE /ADD`?)

Comment: Julien .... Please post a comment whether or not the duplicated post link helps you. That seems like a quick close to me but perhaps he's certain your needed solution is there. That might be the quickest close ever for a legit question.

Comment: Thanks @PimpJuiceIT, I think your solution could work but I have no idea how to implement it. Can you give me a step by step ? Basically, I want to route everything outside of the VPN, except for some IPs that I want to ssh into. The other question do not explain how to do that

Comment: Okay so for an example without using the last `METRIC` parameter in the command, you can see a helpful post I wrote up: https://superuser.com/questions/1260326/routing-between-two/1260655#1260655. Furthermore, regarding split-tunneling and changing static routes when connected to a VPN is concerned, I think my write-up here will clarify on that topic a bit further too in a clear manner: https://superuser.com/questions/1418316/windows-10-splittunneling-internet-not-working/1431181#1431181. Curious to know your thoughts after you look those posts over and think for a sec regarding your config.

Comment: You will want to use the metric parameter if you can get a roue added not disconnecting your from your VPN connection. The metric gives the route precedence rule wise for which interface the traffic will skate across based on subnet of IP address too I suppose. What syntax to use is trivial, what environment and subnets and routes and VPN policies you are working with is probably more important. Dig into it some and think and tag me back and I will guide you the best I can even if you have to open a different question unfortunately.

Comment: There is some added help on routes in the Pulse Secure document below. You may wish to look at this. Can you ask your company to assist with adding split tunneling?  https://docs.pulsesecure.net/WebHelp/PCS/8.3R3/Content/PCS/PCS_AdminGuide_8.3/Defining_VPN_Tunneling_Role.htm

Comment: What you want is specifically controlled by the configuration of the VPN Server itself not the client running on your machine.  If you are unable to make modifications to the VPN Server itself then you will be unable to make the required changes to accomplish your goal.  *Even though I believe this question should remain closed for entirely different reasons, I went ahead, and fixed the numerous grammatical mistakes.*